# Wordpress stripping html and script tags from some admin users on save

Tags: admin, permissions, content-restriction

When I add content to a page as the original admin user, I can past in the following code and it saves fine (old google search set up by another user):

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/cse" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="searchbox_001294947689528032268:0gmklvjoyzm" method="get">
    <input name="cx" type="hidden" value="001294947689528032268:0gmklvjoyzm" />
    <input name="q" size="40" type="text" /> <input name="sa" type="submit" value="Search" />
    <input name="cof" type="hidden" value="FORID:0" />
</form>
<p>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=searchbox_001294947689528032268%3A0gmklvjoyzm" type="text/javascript"></script>
</p>
```

Unfortunately other users that I created on the same site, set as administrators can paste in the same code on a page, but as soon as they hit update, wordpress strips the above code and only inserts:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/cse" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="get">
</form>
<p></p>
```

Why is it stripping content from other users with the administrator role, but not the original admin user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super Admins have different privileges than other admins. By default WordPress strips out a lot of html tags from all users by the super admin. (Assuming that the super admin must be trusted, but most users should not be trusted by default to put in iframes, inputs and other such lovely tags.